# DynamoDBMapper v2 exception

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I downloaded version 1.4.5 of the AWS Java SDK and I'm having trouble migrating a query on a DynamoDB table.  This is a simple hash + range query.

V1 works ok:

```
Condition c = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LT)
                         .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue(new Date().toString()));
DynamoDBQueryExpression q = new DynamoDBQueryExpression(new  AttributeValue("john")).withRangeKeyCondition(c);
```

V2 of the api seems to work a little different. Method signature changes require the code to be re-written as:

```
Condition c = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LT)
                                 .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue(new Date().toString()));
DynamoDBQueryExpression q = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
                                    .withIndexName("user")
                                    .withHashKeyValues("john")
                                    .withRangeKeyCondition("timestamp", c);
```

The AWS SDK throws an exception:

```
The range key(timestamp) in the query is the primary key of the table, not the range key of index(user)
```

Does any one have a code sample illustrating how to execute a query with the new v2 api for DynamoDB?

Comment: What are the hash and range attribute names?

Comment: Chen, the table name is Users with a hash and range key. The has is "user" and range is "timestamp".  Note: Since i posted this on StackOverflow, I have been able to get this working with the AWS low-level Java APIs.  I still have not been able to figure this out using the higher level APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this is late, but if it helps you or anyone else, the problem with your code is when you call `.withIndexName("john")`.

You use `withIndexName()` to query using a local or global secondary index; not for queries using the hash key or hash key and range key of the table.  DynamoDB is looking for a local or global secondary index named `"john"` when what you want to do is search for items with a hash key of `"john"`.